# List of glossaries not displaying

Tags: glossaries

I am using the following code for the list of glossaries, but the list of glossaries do not generate (the code compiles well). Can anybody suggest what may be the problem?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
\newglossaryentry{utc}{Coordinated Universal Time}
\newglossaryentry{adt}{Atlantic Daylight Time}
\newglossaryentry{est}{Eastern Standard Time}

The code is for testing the glossaries list.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: You seem to have no commands like `\glsadd{utc}` in your document. Defining a glossary entry via `\newglossaryentry` does not provide a glossary at all.

Comment: I think you may be wanting `\newacronym` rather than `\newglossaryentry`, given you have used the `acronym` option. (In which case, you need an extra argument `\newacronym{utc}{utc}{Coordinated Universal Time}`.) Also, I recommend you move the definitions to the preamble as in @ChristianHupfer's answer (see [Drawbacks With Defining Entries in the Document Environment](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:docdefs))

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: I already wondered about the entries in the document section, and about the `acronym` option etc, but I did not want to change too much on the MWE

Comment: For those that have a working example (with displayed glossary lists) off-line and only have this problem in Overleaf, someone gave a solution in [this answer over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66924898/7437143).

Answer (score 8):

There are some keys missing in the definition of the glossary entries, amongst other issues.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{utc}{name=utc,description={Coordinated Universal Time}}
\newglossaryentry{adt}{name=adt,description={Atlantic Daylight Time}}
\newglossaryentry{est}{name=est,description={Eastern Standard Time}}

\makeglossaries
\begin{document}

The code is for testing the glossaries list.

%Adding the acronyms to the glossary without displaying them here:
\glsadd{utc}\glsadd{adt}\glsadd{est}

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Compile, for example, with this 'pipeline'

> pdflatex foo
>
> makeindex -s foo.ist -o foo.gls foo.glo
>
> pdflatex foo

**Edit** See the comment by user *`cmhughes`* for other ways to generate the document with the glossary.

**Edit** Usage of the `makeglossaries` script is of course much easier in order to generate the glossaries.

[image]

For further usage, I refer to the documentation of the package, see for example http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossariesbegin.pdf

Comment: +1 note that you can simply use `glsaddall` instead of manually using `\gls` for all of the different entries; also, there is the `makeglossaries` script which is (afaik) a shortcut for the `makeindex` command you gave. there's also `arara`, which can help :)

Comment: @cmhughes: I think I heard of `\glsaddall`, but I never use it, but thanks. As well for `\makeglossaries` etc. I am just accustomed to call it by hand or in a makefile

Comment: I show following error for the same code. "Input index file acronyms.idx not found. Usage: makeindex [-ilqrcgLT] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]". CAn you please suggest what is wrong?

Comment: @mustamus: See my (already yesterday written) pipeline of compiling this document. It is also described in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that after assigning all the \gls{} to your terms, you need to compile the file once.

Then in the command line type:

```
makeglossaries Filename
makeindex -s Filename.ist -t Filename.glg -o Filename.gls Filename.glo
makeindex -s Filename.ist -t Filename.alg -o Filename.acr Filename.acn
```

The tricky part here is to first compile all your code. Then make/update these files by running the command written here and then compiling your code again. In other words, you need to compile twice for the glossary to appear.