# Problems with gloss package

Tags: glossaries

I have been trying to make an glossary using gloss package, but anytime I get the warning  no driver for entry "gd" or "gloss definition".

Basically i have the next code:

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{gloss}

\makegloss

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\gloss[nocite]{*}

\printgloss{glsbase,glosario.bib}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Glosario}

\input{Introduccion}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

I hope somebody can help me, please!

Comment: I believe you're mistaking `gloss` for `glossaries`.

Comment: There is indeed a `gloss` package on CTAN, using `bibtex` apparently, but I never tried it so far. It is from 2002, so it might be a little *aged* ;-)

Comment: so you think it´s better using glossaries package?

Comment: @Eli: I have not compared, but since `glossaries` is continously updated, I would suggest to use that. The author of `glossaries` is also a user here on TeX.SX, so if there are some problems, just ask ;-)

Comment: @Eli: For a quick setup, perhaps this question might help:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192378/list-of-glossaries-not-displaying/192381#192381

Comment: @ChristianHupfer An answer?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use `glossaries` instead of `gloss` which hasn't been updated since 2002.

The document below shows the basic usage. See glossaries for more information, especially about the `makeglossaries` utility.

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{glossaries}{%
  name={glossaries},
  description={A modern and highly configurable package to generate glossaries},
}

\newglossaryentry{gloss}{%
  name={gloss},
  description={An old package, rather aged},
}

\author{Mr. Gumby}
\title{How not to be seen}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents


Rather use \gls{glossaries} and not \gls{gloss} nowadays as of \today. 


\printglossaries


\end{document}
```