# printglossaries, makeglossaries: (0 entries accepted, 0 rejected)

Tags: glossaries

I'm trying to create a glossary for my document but am having trouble getting it to show up.

The last three lines of my document are:

```
\newpage
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

I've also got:

```
\makeglossaries
```

before

```
\begin{document}
```

I tried running:

> makeindex -l -s report.ist -o report.gls report.glo

And also:

> makeglossaries report.glo

Both times, the output was:

```
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2013] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning style file ./report.ist.............................done (29 attributes redefined, 0 ignored).
Scanning input file report.glo...done (0 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Nothing written in report.gls.
Transcript written in report.ilg.
```

I tried following this [tutorial](http://texblog.org/2014/01/15/glossary-and-list-of-acronyms-with-latex/). I also looked at the [beginners guide](http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossariesbegin.pdf), which actually shows `\printglossary` as the command. I tried both, neither worked. The acronyms I have defined in the document are behaving as expected, I just don't see a glossary at the end of my report documenting them. Can you give me any pointers?

Comment: How about stripping down your document into having just a single glossary entry and seeing if that works. If it still doesn't, post that (very [minimal](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)) document here and we can look at it. Here's a silly question: Did you compile your document before running `makeindex`?

Comment: Do you have `\newglossaryentry` commands and something like `\gls`, `\glsall` in you document at all?

Comment: Welcome to the site! You can find a complete MWE here, for example: [List of glossaries not displaying](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/192378)

Comment: It's better not to include the extension when you run `makeglossaries`. If you have multiple glossaries (e.g. if you have used the `acronym` option), `makeglossaries report.glo` will only make the `main` glossary not any of the other glossaries.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) this is just guesswork, but as you mentioned that you have defined acronyms and they are behaving as expected, I suspect you have used the `acronym` package option, like this:

```
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
```

This creates *two* glossaries. The default `main` glossary and the `acronym` glossary. In this case, any acronyms defined using `\newacronym` will be assigned to the `acronym` glossary (unless you explicitly change the glossary type). Any entries defined using `\newglossaryentry` (without designating a type) will automatically be assigned to the `main` glossary.

Each glossary has its own associated file used to store information for `makeindex` (or `xindy`) to process. The file used for the `main` glossary has the extension `.glo`. The file used for the `acronym` glossary has the extension `.acn`.

> ```
> Scanning input file report.glo...done (0 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
> ```

This message from `makeindex` indicates that the `.glo` file is empty. This means that you haven't referenced any entries in the **main** glossary. If you have defined and referenced acronyms in your document, then they are in another file, and that's the file that needs to be processed by `makeindex`. The easiest way to ensure that all files are processed is to use `makeglossaries` *without specifying an extension*:

```
makeglossaries report
```

You wrote that you tried

> ```
> makeglossaries report.glo
> ```

which tells `makeglossaries` to only process the `.glo` file and ignore any other glossary files.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{abc}{ABC}{a contrived acronym}

\begin{document}

\gls{abc}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

If this file is called `test.tex`, then `pdflatex test` will create (amongst other files) `test.glo` (which is empty) and `test.acn` (which has one line). Now, `makeglossaries test` will create a file called `test.acr` and will complain that `test.glo` is empty. The next time you run `pdflatex test`, `\printglossaries` will input `test.acr` and the list of acronyms will be displayed.

If you don't intend to use the `main` glossary, then I recommend you suppress its creation using the `nomain` package option. This will prevent the creation of an unnecessary file and will stop `makeglossaries` from complaining about the empty `.glo` file.

Answer (score 3):

Add `\glsaddall` before `\printglossaries`.

Comment: Adding a little but *complete* document with your suggestion would certainly increase the quality of your answer.

Comment: And welcome to TeX.SX!