# VS Code - LaTeX Workshop usage of glossaries package

Tags: compiling, glossaries

If you are wondering, I am aware of [List of glossaries not displaying](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/192378/178690) and [VS Code - Latex Workshop - custom recipes file location](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/478865/178690). Unfortunately, neither solves my problem.

I am using the LaTeX Workshop extension of VS Code (on my Mac if that matters) and am trying to make a glossary from the `glossaries` package show up. Everything from said package except the glossary at the bottom of the document appears to be working. I believe, based on my reading on [GitHub](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/issues/238), that the problem is that the `makeglossaries` script is not being run when I compile my `.tex` file. Unfortunately, that GitHub link is more than a little above my head (actually I have next to no idea what it is saying), and could use some help implementing its solution (or would appreciate a different solution, if there is a better one).

By clicking on the Settings gear on the LaTeX Workshop extension, I have managed to open `settings.json`, which currently contains the following miscellaneous settings, which I guess I must have set at some point.

```
{
    "latex-workshop.view.pdf.viewer": "tab",
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "cSpell.userWords": [
        "parameterizations",
        "parameterizes"
    ],

    "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
    "editor.largeFileOptimizations": false
}
```

If you're curious about my current .tex file that is failing, it is the first MWE from [the Overleaf Glossaries page](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/glossaries), pasted below for convenience.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
    name=latex,
    description={Is a mark up language specially suited 
    for scientific documents}
}

\newglossaryentry{maths}
{
    name=mathematics,
    description={Mathematics is what mathematicians do}
}

\title{How to create a glossary}
\author{ }
\date{ }

\begin{document}
\maketitle

The \Gls{latex} typesetting markup language is specially suitable 
for documents that include \gls{maths}. 

\clearpage

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

I'm guessing that the things that I've listed may be helpful, but if I can provide anything else, please leave a comment letting me know! By the way, I managed to get the glossary to show up once by pasting something into `settings.json`, so I know its possible, but I'm not sure what that piece of code was, and I have not been able to replicate the result.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which recipe do you use for compiling? latexmk?

Comment: @Wulle I'm not quite sure. I press Cmd + Alt + B to compile. If this doesn't answer your question, how can I find out which recipe I use?

Comment: Just as an fyi, you have to insert \gls{yourglosentry} somewhere to trigger it being displayed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you compile with LaTeX Workshop, the extension needs to know, what commands it is supposed to run and in which order. Therefore you have to use so called "recipes" (defines which command, how often and in which order) which consist of different "tools" (one command with some options). You can define both in the settings.json (which you already found). What you want to do now is to define a recipe which runs pdflatex first, then makeglossaries and after that (maybe biber and) pdflatex (twice) again. This is described on the Github page of your third link. The minimum you would need is:

```
"latex-workshop.latex.recipes":[
        {
            "name": "pdflatex, makeglossaries, pdflatex (2x)",
            "tools": [
                "pdflatex",
                "makeglossaries",
                "pdflatex",
                "pdflatex"
            ]
        },
    ],
    "latex-workshop.latex.tools":[
        {
            "name": "pdflatex",
            "command": "pdflatex",
            "args": [
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "%DOC%"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "makeglossaries",
            "command": "makeglossaries",
            "args": [
              "%DOCFILE%"
            ]
          }
    ],
```

Put it in your settings.json and don't forget to "reload" the window (press CTRL+SHIFT+P and search for it). After that you will have the recipe under the TeX-Extension-Menu (in the left toolbar) under "Build LaTeX project"

You might also want to add other recipes. For example for only one pdflatex run (which will be faster).

```
{
    "name": "pdflatex",
    "tools":[
        "pdflatex",
    ]
},
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: This seemed to mostly work. I'm not quite sure what you mean by Ctrl + Shift + P to reload the window (I just quit the application entirely and reopened it and it seemed to have the same effect). I also found that it worked better if I kept the default recipes and added this one in as an extra. Regardless, thanks much for the expedient and correct reply, +1 and accept!

Comment: thanks for accepting the answer, @ShadyPuck! You are right. Restarting the application has the same effect. But if you change the settings more often, reloading is faster than quitting and reopening it every time.

Comment: Also keep in mind that you have to install perl to run makeglossaries. Most recommended is [StrawberryPerl](https://strawberryperl.com) (which also has a portable version which requires no admin rights to install, as mentioned by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5869154/13624968)).